# Receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS message with the following code

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to Objective C, so I'm not really even sure what this message means:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

When executing the following code:

```
-(void)HelloWorld
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/service.asmx/HelloWorld"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

    //do post request for parameter passing 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //set the content type to JSON
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection release];
    [request release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    // Store incoming data into a string
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

I'm attempting to integrate with the Json Framework.

I call HelloWorld, which executes an async request to my service.  What's strange, is that it worked one time, and now I get this EXC_BAD_ACCESS message every subsequent time.  Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: Naming convention: `-(void)helloWorld`

Comment: @raidfive Thanks, transitioning from .NET ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be releasing the request. It's already autoreleased.

Comment: i'd like to add that autorelease visible by the naming convention of the method. Remember the following: methods with and 'copy', 'alloc' in the name should be released manually.

Comment: Actually it's method starting by "copy", "alloc", "retain", and "new"

Answer (score 2):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you have a bad pointer. In your case, it's because you are releasing the request when it's already autoreleased.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another problem with your code (unrelated to the crash). You create an NSURLConnection and immediately release the connection after creation. When creating an asynchronous connection, you should release the connection in the delegate methods (if connection fails or if connection did finish loading).